# Unable to connect to AWS Keyspaces from a Lambda in a VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-keyspaces

I have followed the instructions [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_dotnetcore_driver.html) and created the infrastructure that I think I need using Terraform. However, I get this error when trying to connect:

```
{
  "errorType": "AggregateException",
  "errorMessage": "One or more errors occurred. (All hosts tried for query failed (tried 172.31.41.121:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'; 172.31.18.20:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'))",
  "stackTrace": [
    "at lambda_method(Closure , Stream , Stream , LambdaContextInternal )"
  ],
  "cause": {
    "errorType": "NoHostAvailableException",
    "errorMessage": "All hosts tried for query failed (tried 172.31.41.121:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'; 172.31.18.20:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.')",
    "stackTrace": [
      "at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)",
      "at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.InitAsync()",
      "at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)",
      "at Cassandra.Cluster.Init()",
      "at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)"
    ]
  },
  "causes": [
    {
      "errorType": "NoHostAvailableException",
      "errorMessage": "All hosts tried for query failed (tried 172.31.41.121:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.'; 172.31.18.20:9142: AuthenticationException 'The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.')",
      "stackTrace": [
        "at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.Connect(Boolean isInitializing)",
        "at Cassandra.Connections.Control.ControlConnection.InitAsync()",
        "at Cassandra.Tasks.TaskHelper.WaitToCompleteAsync(Task task, Int32 timeout)",
        "at Cassandra.Cluster.Init()",
        "at Cassandra.Cluster.ConnectAsync(String keyspace)"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

I have created an `aws_vpc_endpoint_service` so I am surprised that this does not work.

```hcl
# Security group for resources that want to access Keyspaces from the VPC
resource "aws_security_group" "keyspaces_endpoint_vpc_access" {
  name   = "keyspaces-endpoint-access"
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.default.id
}

resource "aws_security_group" "keyspaces_endpoint" {
  name   = "keyspaces-endpoint"
  vpc_id = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  ingress {
    from_port       = 9142
    to_port         = 9142
    protocol        = "tcp"
    security_groups = [ aws_security_group.keyspaces_endpoint_vpc_access.id ]
  }
}

data "aws_vpc_endpoint_service" "keyspaces" {
  service = "cassandra"
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "keyspaces_endpoint" {
  vpc_id              = aws_default_vpc.default.id
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"
  service_name        = data.aws_vpc_endpoint_service.keyspaces.service_name
  security_group_ids  = [ aws_security_group.keyspaces_endpoint.id ]
  private_dns_enabled = true

  subnet_ids = [
    data.aws_subnet.selected.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_a.id,
    aws_default_subnet.subnet_b.id
  ]

  policy  = <<EOF
      {
        "Statement": [
          {
            "Sid": "keyspaces-full-access",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "cassandra:*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
          }
        ]
      }
    EOF
}

resource "aws_security_group" "my_func" {
  vpc_id      = aws_default_vpc.default.id

  egress {
    from_port   = 0
    to_port     = 65535
    protocol    = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks = [ "0.0.0.0/0" ]
  }

  lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

resource "aws_lambda_function" "my_func" {
  runtime          = "dotnetcore3.1"
  timeout          = 900
  memory_size      = 512

  # etc.

  vpc_config {
    subnet_ids         = [ data.aws_subnet.selected.id ]
    security_group_ids = [
      aws_security_group.my_func.id,
      aws_security_group.keyspaces_endpoint_vpc_access.id
    ]
  }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong here?**

Comment: Try using the DER format of the Amazon CA root Certificate. Either convert the pem to crt using openssl `openssl x509 -outform der -in AWSCA.pem -out your-cert.crt` or download the DER format certificate from here. https://www.amazontrust.com/repository/AmazonRootCA1.cer. Dont forget to update your function code with new certificate format. :-)

Comment: The `keyspaces_endpoint_vpc_access` security group does not have any explicit `egress` rules listed. Does Terraform give it default "All Outbound" access? (You can check by looking at the security group after it has been deployed.)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: @SRATH I have tried using `.cer` but I get the same error

Answer (score 1):

The problem was the SSL configuration in the Lambda code.

It is crucial to call `SetHostNameResolver`, but apparently only when inside a VPC:

```ml
    let sslOptions =
      SSLOptions()
        .SetCertificateCollection(certCollection)
        .SetHostNameResolver (fun _ -> sprintf "cassandra.%s.amazonaws.com" region)
```